# What are #1 and #2 in the Sort[{{a, 2, 5}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 3, 2}}, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &]?

Tags: sorting

```
Sort[{{a, 2, 5}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 3, 2}}, #1[[3]] < #2[[3]] &]
```

In the above code, the list is ordered based on the third element of each sublist.
But what does #1 or #2 mean here? If #1 refers to the first sublist and #2 the second, then how about using #3[[3]] > #2[[3]? (it fails actually)

Comment: `#i` means the i-th argument of the function.

Answer (score 5):

`#n` stands for the nth variable in a pure function, in this case the ordering function `p`.

From the details of `Sort`:
*"The ordering function p applied to a pair of elements e1, e2 may return either 1, 0, -1"*.

Now replace e1 with #1 and e2 with #2, and you understand that `Less[e1_, e2_]` can also be written as `Less[#1, #2]&` or `#1 < #2 &`.

By the way, you could also use

```
SortBy[#[[3]]&] @ {{a, 2, 5}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 3, 2}}
```

{{d, 3, 2}, {c, 1, 4}, {a, 2, 5}}

Further reading

[Work with pure functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html)

Answer (score 4):

This is an attempt at an illustrative answer and some sources.

The command can, also, be written as

```
Sort[{{a, 2, 5}, {c, 1, 4}, {d, 3, 2}}, 
 Part[Slot[1], 3] < Part[Slot[2], 3] &]
```

which perhaps is a bit more familiar as syntax.

As was pointed in the comment by @Daniel Huber

`#` is [**`Slot`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)

and

`[[]]` is # is [**`Part`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)